# converting a method to a function

Tags: javascript

Is there a trick in Javascript, to create a normal function from a method?

Specifically, I want to convert the String.prototype.toLowerCase method to a function that accepts a string.

The obvious solution is:

```
var toLowerCase = function(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
}
```

But I wonder if there is a shorter way to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: why not directly use s.toLowerCase()...!

Comment: @Sudhir Perhaps because he wants to pass the function as a parameter to another function that expects a certain signature.

Comment: OP, why din't you accept Freakih's answer ? If it doesn't suit you please explain your need better.

Comment: I asked for "a shorter way to achieve this" (see my question). While the solution of freakish is good in general, it is not shorter in this specific case. In any case, I accepted the answer because it is the best available :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function which will convert a method to a function:

```
var converter = function(method) {
    return function(instance) {
        return method.call(instance);
    };
};
var toLowerCase = converter(String.prototype.toLowerCase);
```

If you want to pass additional arguments then you can use this version:

```
var converter = function(method) {
    return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            instance = args.shift()
        return method.apply(instance, args);
    };
};
```

Example:

```
> var replace = converter(String.prototype.replace);
> replace("TEST", "T", "X");
"XESX"
```